# How do I access the directory I want?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to access files in the desired directory through listObjectsV2.
I used prefix to come to the directory I wanted.
I don't know what to do because I even get files in the sub-directory under that directory.

my code

```
s3.listObjectsV2(
        {
          Bucket : "seunghyuncodingevery",
          Prefix : "post/",
        },
        (err, data) => {
          if(err) {
            throw err
          }
          let contents = data.Contents
          contents.forEach((content) => {
            console.log(content)
          })
        }
      )
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "access the directory I want?"? Which directory? If your code works, then what else do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you would like to list the contents of an Amazon S3 bucket with a certain prefix, but without the contents of any sub-directories being included in the response.

You can do this by adding `Delimiter : '/'`, which tells S3 that you are treating a slash as a directory divider. It will then only return objects that are in that immediate path, together with a list of `CommonPrefixes` that are effectively the names of sub-directories.